# How to search for existence of array in Kibana?

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-query

I have in Kibana a field that is sometimes a string and sometimes an array.
For example:

```
{ "fld1": "val1", "fld2": "val2"} 
{ "fld1": "val3", "fld2": [ "val4", "val5" ] }
```

I want to search for documents that contain an array in "fld2".

I tried:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['fld2'].size > 0",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the output you are received for which you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search script return String for doc['fld2'] value, You have to convert it into array for checking size.

```js
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "def val = doc['fld2']; val.size() > 1",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting and error "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [fld2] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead", but this seems the correct way to go, Thanks!

Comment: You can change mapping for "fld2" to enable fielddata like. PUT <TYPE>/_mapping
{
  "properties" : {
    "fld2" : {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true
      }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like :
`"source": "if ((ctx._source.doc['fld2'] instanceof List})) { /* do something here */}",`